# MS Access - Aggregate Query issues

Tags: sql, ms-access, relational-database

I have a database that tracks students community service hours based on if they attended an event. The relationship is established correctly but where I'm running into an issue is with the aggregate query.

This is the logic that I am attempting to do:

```
if(ActivityAttendance.Attended) == 1
   Affiliates.completedHours += Activities.creditHours

(This is just supposed to be more of a pseudo code)
```

The ACTIVITYATTENDANCE is the name of the table that owns the Attended "yes/no" field.
CompletedHours is a field inside of the AFFILIATES table.

I've tried finding a solution, but it seems that all I can find online is the ability to sum the number of yes's and the number of no's. I've attached a picture of the relationship for better understanding.

Is this something that can be accomplished using the basic Access features or is there a SQL solution?

Since I'm new to stack I could not post the image directly, but I have uploaded it here:

http://s22.postimg.org/g0r53vgtd/Capture.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an IIF() with Sum in the SELECT line of aggregate query:

```
SELECT Affiliates.StudentID, Affiliates.[First Name], Affiliates.[Last Name], 
Sum(IIF(ActivityAttendance.Attended = True, Affiliates.[Completed Hours], 0)) As AttendedServiceHours
FROM Affiliates 
INNER JOIN ActivityAttendance ON Affiliates.StudentID = ActivityAttendance.StudentID
GROUP BY Affiliates.StudentID, Affiliates.[First Name], Affiliates.[Last Name]
```

Alternatively, you can use WHERE clause in your aggregate query:

```
SELECT Affiliates.StudentID, Affiliates.[First Name], Affiliates.[Last Name], 
Sum(Affiliates.[Completed Hours]) As AttendedServiceHours
FROM Affiliates 
INNER JOIN ActivityAttendance ON Affiliates.StudentID = ActivityAttendance.StudentID
WHERE ActivityAttendance.Attended = True
GROUP BY Affiliates.StudentID, Affiliates.[First Name], Affiliates.[Last Name]
```

Comment: Thank you for that! That helped, but it only got to me the halfway point. I am still stuck on trying to figure out how I can take those "AttendedServiceHours" and total them, and then set that total to Completed Hours.

I understand that you can use a "total" function in the datasheet view, but that doesn't allow me to take that total and assign its value to another field.

Comment: I am not understanding. The above queries does total Completed Hours by each distinct Student and this field is named AttendedServiceHours. Do you need grand total hours across all students? And do you need Completed Hours updated which will require a different update query?

Comment: Sorry, let me attempt to clarify,

What I am trying to accomplish is if a student attends one event that is worth 4 credit hours, the "Affiliates.[Completed Hours]" field is updated to 4. And then if the student attends another event that is worth 5 credit hours, the "Affiliates.[Completed Hours]" field is updated to 9.


The "AttendedServiceHours" is not actually totaling the hours, it's just going Event by Event and totaling the Credit Hours for each event. The problem there is that a student can attend more than one event. So how do I go about summing all events attended by a student?